# Why Xamarin.Forms WebView increases Android app storage data size?

Tags: android, webview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms app with a feature using `WebView`. It opens a simple web page.

Every time I open a webpage in it, app's storage data size increases. I check it on Android/Settings/App info/Storage. My app size is ~15 MB, but after opening some pages, it goes to 50 MB and so on. What is it doing? Caching? Or...? How can I disable it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that it is the cache of the `WebView`. Unfortunately, the Cache of the Forms WebView is not configurable. So you have to write a custom renderer and disable it on the native view. Add this class to your Android Project.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(NoChacheWebViewRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid.Renderer
{

    public class NoChacheWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null) return;

            Control.ClearCache(true);
            Control.Settings.SetAppCacheEnabled(false);
            Control.Settings.CacheMode = CacheModes.NoCache;
        }
    }
}
```